# How do I remove unnamed headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm able to read in multiple datasets into a dictionary, however, I keep getting a header row with an unnamed title.

```
           Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  \
     0           year      month        day       hour     minute       WDIR   
     1           2016         01         01         00         00         15   
     2           2016         01         01         00         06         14   
     3           2016         01         01         00         12         12   
     4           2016         01         01         00         18         15   
     5           2016         01         01         00         24         19   
     6           2016         01         01         00         30         15
```

How can I get rid of it and make my row 0 be the header?

Here is the code I used:

```
 values = ['2015','2016','2017','2018']
 mother_data = {}
 keys = range(4)
 for i in keys:
     mother_data[i] = pd.read_csv('data/pcbf1h'+values[i]+'_df.csv', sep=",")
```

Comment: In your call to `read_csv`, there is an argument which allows you to set column names. Read the docs. I also don’t see why you would use a dictionary where the keys are simple ints like this. Why not iterate over the `values` list and use those as keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `header` argument:

```
values = ['2015','2016','2017','2018']
mother_data = {}
keys = range(4)
for i in keys:
    mother_data[i] = pd.read_csv('data/pcbf1h'+values[i]+'_df.csv', sep=",", header=0)
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be `header=0`, since it’s the first row of the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

```py
 values = ['2015','2016','2017','2018']
 mother_data = {}
 keys = range(4)
 for i in keys:
     mother_data[i] = pd.read_csv('data/pcbf1h'+values[i]+'_df.csv', sep=",", \
                      skiprows=1, header=0)
```

Comment: Why the `skiprows`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]  
df=df[1:]
df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index(drop=True) 

   year month day hour minute WDIR
0  2016    01  01   00     00   15
1  2016    01  01   00     06   14
2  2016    01  01   00     12   12
3  2016    01  01   00     18   15
4  2016    01  01   00     24   19
5  2016    01  01   00     30   15
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, using `header` is probably the solution you need, although depending on the source data, you may actually want `header=0` (since that's the first line of the file, wile `header=1` references the second).

Also, your code can be a lot shorter in Python:

```
mother_data = {}
for year in ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']:
    mother_data[year] = pd.read_csv(f'data/pcbf1h{year}_df.csv', sep=',', header=0)
```

Note that the 'years' don't have to be strings, you could also just use integers, i.e. `[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]`

Possibly most Pythonic:

```
mother_data = {
    year: pd.read_csv(f'data/pcbf1h{year}_df.csv', sep=',', header=0)
    for year in [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the rest of the code, it’s important too :)